# Locked out of Vagrant box by bad .bashrc. Can I use Vagrantfile to get back in?

Tags: vagrant

I have a vagrant box running under the default user vagrant. I access the shell with Putty and a keyfile. I'm on Windows.

I added this command to the end of .bashrc

```
if [[ ! $TERM =~ screen ]]; then
    exec tmux
fi
```

in an effort to start tmux automatically when I started a session.

But now the shell exits after it loads tmux. I don't get a chance to do anything before it exits.

I've been taking advice on Reddit https://www.reddit.com/r/linuxquestions/comments/ahvdwn/locked_out_of_shell_by_command_in_bashrc_can_i/

So I've tried a lot of things from the logging in side of things but nothing is working.

So my question here is can I use the Vagrantfile to gain access to the box through an alternative configuration? Can I bypass the box's internal setup which is password access turned off, no root access, ssh keyed access for the vagrant user, no ftp (only sftp which uses the secured user).

Answer (score 0):

Under Linux, the commands below would have granted access :

```
vagrant ssh-config > my_ssh_config
ssh -q -F my_ssh_config vagrant@broken-host '/bin/bash --norc --noprofile'
```

On Windows, I suppose that you have to use plink.exe to achieve something similar. Good luck.

Comment: As per the advice given on Reddit (link above), attempts of that nature resulted in "open terminal failed: not a terminal" error. In all attempts, ,bashrc loads, loads tmux per the above code, and immediately exits dropping the connection. --norc has zero effect

Answer (score 0):

There is a method for fixing the .bashrc from outside vagrant machine without editing the Vagrantfile. You can use `scp` command to replace the existing .bashrc inside the virtual machine using another copy.

```
$scp -P 2222 -i <path_to_the_private_key_file> -r .bashrc vagrant@127.0.0.1:/home/vagrant/.bashrc
```